# Apply an alpha to a color mathematically

Tags: objective-c, colors

How does one get the colour value (rgb) after applying an alpha to a colour?

I would like to apply an alpha to a colour and get the rgb values from the result.

Maybe I am over thinking this, or is it just the value e.g. 120 * alpha (0.6) = resulting colour? White is at 255 though, so should it be 120 += 120 * alpha (0.6) ?

Comment: The alpha parameter determines how much the background "shines through", so the resulting color depends on the background color.

Comment: I have access to the background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting color of the pixel would be dependent on what color was painted behind it, if the color is partially transparent. Which makes this far more complex that you might think.

The `rgb` values of the color do not change at all when you apply the alpha.  All the changes is how that color will blend with other elements in the view.

So you would have to know where on the screen the color will be drawn, and query the view for the color at that pixel, and then blend it with your color according to the colors alpha value.

```
//psuedocode
resultColor = (backgroundColor * (1 - alpha)) + (myColor * alpha)
```

So if your alpha was `0.2` you blend the colors so the result is 80% background color and 20% foreground color.

Comment: I have the background color

Comment: Well then blend them! I gave the basic math above. Do that for r, g and b each and you should be there.

Comment: Thanks. :) just saying, so I don't have to grab the individual pixel values.

Comment: What datatype is used for the colour values? How is the colour represented?

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW47) rgb and alpha values are `CGFloat` type normalized from `0.0` to `1.0`, which should make this math simple.

Comment: So caught up in a refactor I cant think straight :/ thanks for the patience.